# Burn installer doesn't uninstall the MSI

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer, bundle, bootstrapper

My burn installer doesn't uninstals the msi on some PC's
After running the uninstall process the app still remains in programs.
Here is uninstall log difference:

[264C:15B0][2014-10-07T16:24:00]i201: Planned package: Installer.msi, state: Present, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: Uninstall, rollback: Install, cache: No, uncache: Yes, dependency: Unregister

for successful uninstall and

[08F4:1254][2014-10-07T15:19:34]i201: Planned package: Installer.msi, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: Yes, dependency: Unregister

for failed uninstall.
I was wondering what can cause this issue and how it can be managed?

Comment: And one more clue, the message from install log of problematic installation : [153C:1320][2014-10-07T15:18:55]w355: Unable to register source directory: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{C378826B-1AF2-4490-BB68-7B3F6C4775E3}v1.0.0.155\, product: {C378826B-1AF2-4490-BB68-7B3F6C4775E3}, reason: 0x80070645. Continuing...

Comment: If you want to add more, you can access the edit link at the bottom of your question - you shouldn't ever need to (as you have here) write a comment in direct reply to yourself.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem.As, I am facing a similar issue.